# Pandas: Pivot DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm new to Python and have been learning manipulating data through Pandas. Right now, I pulled in data from a JSON file and one of the columns looks like this.

I've tried using pandas, JSON & ijson modules to open it up - but I can't make it work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to convert this into a dataframe with 'ID' and 'variantColor' as column headers?

```
0
0   {'ID': '615454762062', 'variantColor': 'JJ0BVE...
1   {'ID': '615454762222', 'variantColor': 'JJ0BVE...
2   {'ID': '615454762307', 'variantColor': 'JJ0BVE...
3   {'ID': '615454772788', 'variantColor': 'JJ0FHA...
4   {'ID': '615454773525', 'variantColor': 'JJ1ANC...
5   {'ID': '615454762109', 'variantColor': 'JJ0BVE...
6   {'ID': '615454762185', 'variantColor': 'JJ0BVE...
7   {'ID': '615454772863', 'variantColor': 'JJ0FHA...
8   {'ID': '615454773402', 'variantColor': 'JJ1ANC...
9   {'ID': '615454773600', 'variantColor': 'JJ1ANC...
10  {'ID': '615454762024', 'variantColor': 'JJ0BVE...
11  {'ID': '615454762260', 'variantColor': 'JJ0BVE...
12  {'ID': '615454772665', 'variantColor': 'JJ0FHA...
13  {'ID': '615454773327', 'variantColor': 'JJ1ANC...
14  {'ID': '615454773440', 'variantColor': 'JJ1ANC...
15  {'ID': '615454762147', 'variantColor': 'JJ0BVE...
16  {'ID': '615454772740', 'variantColor': 'JJ0FHA...
17  {'ID': '615454772825', 'variantColor': 'JJ0FHA...
18  {'ID': '615454772900', 'variantColor': 'JJ0FHA...
19  {'ID': '615454772948', 'variantColor': 'JJ0FHA...
20  {'ID': '615454773280', 'variantColor': 'JJ1ANC...
21  {'ID': '615454773365', 'variantColor': 'JJ1ANC...
22  {'ID': '615454762345', 'variantColor': 'JJ0BVE...
23  {'ID': '615454772627', 'variantColor': 'JJ0FHA...
24  {'ID': '615454772702', 'variantColor': 'JJ0FHA...
25  {'ID': '615454773488', 'variantColor': 'JJ1ANC...
26  {'ID': '615454773563', 'variantColor': 'JJ1ANC...`
```

Comment: Your expected output? And can you say the result of  `type(df[0][0])`

Comment: `type(df[0][0])` gives a `dict` result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use apply pd.Series by selecting the column if they are in dict format i.e

```
ndf = df[0].apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Dude, you're awesome! That worked :) Can you explain what was wrong, so that i know what to do the next time i encounter this problem

Comment: @Abhay It might be because it was a nested json file. So you need to apply pd.Series to one more level.